# Android VideoView can't play video in "file:///android_asset/..."

Tags: android

I'm trying to play video:

```
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);


String viewSource = "file:///android_asset/intro.mp4";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(viewSource);

mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);  
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

but nothing works. LogCat shows me just this: "MediaPlayer Error(1, -2147483648)"

If i try to play video from res/raw directory, everythig works fine! But i need to play from ASSETS!!!

Thanks.

Comment: you need it from assets because?

Comment: I'm porting a game and using using NDK for it. All code in C++. I need to play video for example in intro scene. I want to use videoview from java side. Now i'm trying to play video from full-java android app

Comment: I am not familiar with NDK development but you still haven't answered my question: Why do you need it from the assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

Start the video from callback that the player provides in this manner:

```
mVideoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://<<package>>/raw/video");
mVideoView.requestFocus();

mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mVideoView.start();
    }
});
mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }
});
```